# RxXdfData, RxTextData, rxXdfToDataFrame

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I'm trying to find out what these functions do but I can't find much information on it and it is not very clear from what I have found out. What do they do?

Answer (score 1):

When you start out using Revo R or see demonstrations given, it's common to see functions being applied directly to a file path, like this:

```
# Create a point to an insurance claims dataset installed with RRE
xdfPath <- file.path(rxGetOption("sampleDataDir"), "claims.xdf")

rxDataStep(xdfPath, numRows = 6)
```

Behind the scenes, though, `rxDataStep` is creating a wrapper around that file path with the information it needs to work with it - the file type, which variables to read, whether character vectors should be converted to factors, etc. That wrapper is called a "data source", and `RxXdfData` is the function used to create it. `RxTextData` is the same thing, just for text files:

```
# Create a point to an insurance claims dataset installed with RRE
textPath <- file.path(rxGetOption("sampleDataDir"), "claims.txt")

rxDataStep(textPath, numRows = 6)
```

You can often just let the RRE functions take care of this for you. Creating a data source can be useful if you have a file that should have different default settings in different analyses. They also have one other advantage: because a data source is a real R object, instead of just a file path, you can use a handful open-source R functions on them:

```
# This doesn't work like we'd expect:
head(xdfPath)

# These do:
xdfSource <- RxXdfData(xdfPath)
head(xdfSource)
names(xdfSource)
nrow(xdfSource)
summary(xdfSource)
```

Which is neat but not world-changing.

`rxXdfToDataFrame` just lets you convert an XDF file into an in-memory data frame, like this:

```
rxXdfToDataFrame(xdfSource)
```

... which is also what `rxDataStep` does if you don't give it an `outFile`, so I usually use `rxDataStep` because it's easier to type.

Comment: Thanks Matt that makes more sense now....one question if you use rxDataStep and don't specify an outFile, do you need to state overwrite as False for it to convert the xdf into a data frame in memory?

Comment: @vis7 overwrite only applies when you're writing to an XDF file, so no problem there. You do need to assign it a name, though - something like: `claims <- rxDataStep(textPath)`