# How to convert a RxXdfData to a data.frame on R?

Tags: r, knime, revolution-r

Hi I recently integrated Revolution R entreprise to Knime (R nodes). 
I wanted to know if there is a way to convert RxXdfData class into a data.frame for Knime node processing (R snippets handle just data.frame objects). 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019308), you are looking for the [`rxXdfToDataFrame`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RevoScaleR/functions/rxXdfToDataFrame) or the [`rxDataStep`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RevoScaleR/functions/rxXdfToDataFrame) functions to convert to data.frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look for it on the revoR doc.

Comment: It works, thanks for the fast response. 
for further knoledge : while working with large data files with more than 3e+06 rows, change the value of maxRowsByCols =

Comment: @IsmailAkrim set maxRowsByCols to NULL to remove the size check; or you can also use [`rxReadXdf`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RevoScaleR/functions/rxReadXdf).